# Complex SQL Count Query

Tags: sql, hsqldb

Hello I've been stuck with one SQL query for my assignment and was hoping for some help.

I need to get the Project ID for **the best executed project** -the project where (VERY_GOOD record count + GOOD record count) - (VERY_BAD record count + BAD record count) is greatest

My schema and test records in database (HSQLDB)

```
CREATE TABLE
    PROJECT
    (
        ID IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        PROJECT_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE
    RECORD
    (
        ID IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        RESULT VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    );

CREATE TABLE
    RECORD_PROJECT
    (
        PROJECT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        RECORD_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(PROJECT_ID, RECORD_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY (PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PROJECT(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (RECORD_ID) REFERENCES RECORD(ID)
    );
```

And test data:

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_NAME) VALUES ('Bake a cake');
INSERT INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_NAME) VALUES ('Clean the house');

INSERT INTO RECORD (RESULT) VALUES ('GOOD');
INSERT INTO RECORD (RESULT) VALUES ('VERY_GOOD');
INSERT INTO RECORD (RESULT) VALUES ('VERY_GOOD');
INSERT INTO RECORD (RESULT) VALUES ('BAD');
INSERT INTO RECORD (RESULT) VALUES ('VERY_BAD');

INSERT INTO RECORD_PROJECT (PROJECT_ID, RECORD_ID) VALUES (0,0);
INSERT INTO RECORD_PROJECT (PROJECT_ID, RECORD_ID) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO RECORD_PROJECT (PROJECT_ID, RECORD_ID) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO RECORD_PROJECT (PROJECT_ID, RECORD_ID) VALUES (0,3);
INSERT INTO RECORD_PROJECT (PROJECT_ID, RECORD_ID) VALUES (1,4);
```

(I removed unrelated fields from tables)

So with this data I have 3 good records and 2 bad, I would need to get the project which has the highest 'rating', which according to this right now would be **Clean the house** with 3 good ratings over 2 negative for other project.

Maybe someone would figure this out, thanks!

Comment: Are you required to use char for record.result?

Comment: IDENTITY? That's new to me

Comment: The Record is hardcoded value into the database, which I could also solve through enum. For result I just need the ID of the project that has the best results.

Comment: Not related to your question, but the on delete cascade is in the wrong table.

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly it should be then?

Comment: Probably in the project table.  That way if you delete a project, the associated records in record_project also get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

That should be the (not testet) SQL in MySQL-Dialect:

```
SELECT rp.PROJECT_ID, p.PROJECT_NAME
   SUM(CASE WHEN rp.RECORD_ID < 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rating
FROM RECORD_PROJEKT AS rp
JOIN PROJECT AS p ON p.ID = rp.PROJECT_ID
GROUP BY rp.PROJECT_ID
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Comment: Sorry I don't see how this helps me. Seems wrong syntax for hsql.

Comment: @Vaelyr . . . The question is tagged "mysql" not "hsql".

Comment: I think this should work on HSQLDB if you do not include p.PROJECT_NAME. SELECT rp.PROJECT_ID, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN rp.RECORD_ID < 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rating
FROM RECORD_PROJECT AS rp
JOIN PROJECT AS p ON p.ID = rp.PROJECT_ID
GROUP BY rp.PROJECT_ID
ORDER BY rating DESC